# Calculator divide by zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I created a simple calculator. Everything works great; however, if I divide by zero, I would like to show an error message. I know how to do alert popups, but I don't know how to implement it so it comes up when I divide by zero. Here is a snipped of my calculator code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
    if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
    else {
        switch (currentOperation) {
            case 1:
                result = result + currentNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                result = result - currentNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                result = result * currentNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                result = result / currentNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentOperation = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    currentNumber = 0;
    CalcDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",result];
    if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
    currentOperation = [sender  tag];
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;
```

Comment: I don't know how to create a popup in xcode, but basically under case 4 check if currentNumber == 0, if so halt operation and show popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the second division operand is zero, and if yes, then print an error message. Don't forget, that you can't just compare `double` or something with `==`, you have to use presicion, like this:

```
case 4:
    if(ABS(currentNumber) < 1e-12) // most probably its zero
        // your message
        return;
```

Comment: I like your answer. But if I put case 4:
                if(ABS(currentNumber) < 1e-12)
                {
                    CalcDisplay.text = @"Error";}, my display says "6" if i divide 6 by zero...

Comment: You are setting the text in the end of the function. You shouldn't do that. Instead, `return` or something after you printed the Error. Otherwise, it will re-set to a number or anything you tell it.

Comment: Just one remark: cutting of the divisor by some fixed constant is probably a bad idea as `5e-13/1e-12 = 0.5` is a completely sensible calculation.

Comment: @j.holetzeck is right, so I would recommend you to use integer types instead of `double` or something to read just one (next) digit. Then, you can just compare it with `0`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a test prior to doing the division e.g. change:

```
        case 4:
            result = result / currentNumber;
            break;
```

to:

```
        case 4:
            if (currentNumber == 0)
                // ... do alert here ...
            else
                result = result / currentNumber;
            break;
```

Comment: The alert comes up, but my display says "INF," even if I add CalcDisplay.text = @"Error"; Is there a way to show "Error" in the display?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
else {
    switch (currentOperation) {
       case 1:
            result = result + currentNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - currentNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * currentNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            if(currentNumber == 0){
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
            }else{

                result = result / currentNumber;

            }

            break;
        case 5:
            currentOperation = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
currentNumber = 0;
CalcDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
currentOperation = [sender  tag];
userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;
```

Please try this code, I have copied an pasted the code you have given and added some necessary lines to it which i felt would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code, but my CalcDisplay shows "INF," and the alert does not come up...

Comment: I am sorry, I had mistook the if condition you had place. Thankyou for correcting me.